# How to get an error on VSC if the signature of a Typescript Function doesn't return a type

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

Hi I would like to know if there is a way to force TSLint (I guess) in order to get an error if a fucntion does't return a type (at least any).

e.g.

```
cont myFunc(par: string) {
// somthing here
}
```

I would like to have an error there in order to force me to do this

```
cont myFunc(par: string): number { <--This!
// somthing here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tslint.json`, `"call-signature"` must be present under `typedef:`

> ```
> tslint.json
> ```

```
...
  "typedef": [true, "call-signature", "property-declaration"]
...
```